# I deleted my .xcodeproj file, what can I do?

Tags: xcode, recycle-bin, xcodeproj

I accidentally deleted my xcodeproj file (also from trash) I really don't know how it could happen. What should I do now? I have my app on my iPhone, can I do something with that?

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Did that file be added to any source version control, such as git? If yes, you just need to discard that change, and that file will come back.

Comment: @Ontop14 you can create new project and add old sources

Comment: You can follow This https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4070374?tstart=0